# CLion no syntax highlighting and hints for CMakeLists

Tags: cmake, syntax-highlighting, clion

My CMakeLists.txt is correctly loaded for the project, and the project can be executed correctly. However, when I try to write in CMakeLists.txt, there's no syntax highlighting, hints and reload hint as usual. I don't know if I set something wrong.

Comment: Try hitting ctrl+space to check if it works at all.

Comment: I think it doesn't work properly. Only on word "mai" can it gives the suggestion "main", but it doesn't work for other personal-named files.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is native support for CMake in CLion for it. The best alternative I found was [CMake Simple Highlighter](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10089-cmake-simple-highlighter).

The plug-in's author has also created a **paid** version of this (with proper IDE support and hints): [CMake Plus](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/12869-cmake-plus)

Comment: When I first used CLion, there is native CMake syntax highlighting by default.. Thanks for your advice, I'll take a look at the plugin!